# Is there anyway to remove tabbaritem ios?

Tags: ios, view, uitabbaritem

So like i said in the title, my question is :

***Is there anyway to remove one tabbaritem without remove view ?***

I have readed about UITabBarController , but remove the view not the item.

I need to have 4 childViewControllers in my TabBarControlller but only display 3 in my TabBarItems.

Example:

[I have this :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMxWx.png)

**-UITabBarController**

- ViewChildController1
- ViewChildController2
- ViewChildController3
- ViewChildController4

**-Tabbar (bottom) from UITabBarController**
ViewChildItem1 (ViewChildController1)

- ViewChildItem1 (ViewChildController1)
- ViewChildItem2 (ViewChildController2)
- ViewChildItem3 (ViewChildController3)
- ViewChildItem4 (ViewChildController4) ( remove/hide this one only,but still have the ViewChildController4 in UITabBarController )

[I want this without the tabbaritem for the lastview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjtsX.png)

Comment: Why do you want to have a controller, but have no tab bar item to access it? What is you goal?

Comment: Because I have one button in UITabBar ( TOP ) witch is call that ViewController ( tabBarController setSelectedView:myView )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question makes no sense. A tab bar controller *is* a parent view controller that provides access to its children through tab bar items, automatically. That is its *purpose*. If you don't want this, don't use a tab bar controller.

You can disable a child's tab bar item; you can prevent access to a child; but you cannot have a child be present without being a member of the team, as it were.

It is possible that you need to revise your architecture. If you have a fourth view controller that you want to make appear in some other way, then do so - but then, don't make it a child of the tab bar controller. Perhaps what you want is for this fourth view controller to be a *presented* view controller, for instance.